# How to exclude class from build after developpement in VS 2012 vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, development-environment

I have a Helper class in my project that I use to help me develop the application. How do I NOT include this class in the final build when I take the application in production?

I still want the people who are going to do the maintenance to have access to it though.

So the behavior I'm looking for would be for the program to function normally while I'm developing it in Visual studio with the debug configurations. But if I build it with the release configurations, I would get an error for calls to an unknown member (supposing I didn't remove the calls to the Helper).

Sort of the same kind of behavior we have with tests.

An even better solution would not have me remove the calls to the Helper in the code.

Any way to do that?

Please comment if the question is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`ConditionalAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx) on the methods in the class.

Passing in `DEBUG` will mean that only when the DEBUG symbol is defined will the class compile.

> Applying ConditionalAttribute to a method indicates to compilers that a call to the method should not be compiled into Microsoft intermediate language (MSIL) unless the conditional compilation symbol that is associated with ConditionalAttribute is defined.

```
<ConditionalAttribute("DEBUG")> _
Sub Method1(x As Integer)
    Console.WriteLine("DEBUG is defined")
End Sub
```

Comment: Do I have to do it on every methods of the class too? Or just the class itself is ok?

Comment: @SimonCorcos - You can only apply this directly on classes that derive from `Attribute`, so if your class isn't like that, you will need to apply it on every method.